# How to enable swap with salt stack?

Tags: ubuntu, swap, saltstack

How can I create and enable permanent 1GB swap file with salt stack that will work after reboot? `salt.states.mount.swap` does not allow  to define swap size. Furthermore I need to define swappiness. Currently I do it with `echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently use this in production, works for me.

```
community_swap_file:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        [ -f /.swapfile ] || dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swapfile bs=1M count=2048
        chmod 0600 /.swapfile
        mkswap /.swapfile
        echo '/.swapfile      none      swap     sw       0       0' >> /etc/fstab
        swapon -a
    - unless: file /.swapfile 2>&1 | grep -q "Linux/i386 swap"
```

Comment: Note: the "unless" grep is broken on Ubuntu 22, it should be looking for `Linux swap file` as the output is `/.swapfile: Linux swap file, 4k page size, little endian (...)`, if this isn't changed this will always fire, returning `mkswap: error: /.swapfile is mounted`, adding a new line in `fstab` etc. I'd recommend changing `unless` to just do `test -f /.swapfile` and remove `[ -f /.swapfile ]` from the `name` block

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use on debian-based systems. It's an improved version of Dan's answer. It gets the available memory from a grain, multiplies it by 2, to create the swapfile with the appropriate size. It also makes an entry in /etc/fstab, if non-existent.

```
coreutils:
  pkg.installed

/swapfile:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        [ -f /swapfile ] || dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count={{ grains["mem_total"] * 2 }}
        chmod 0600 /swapfile
        mkswap /swapfile
        swapon -a
    - unless:
      - file /swapfile 2>&1 | grep -q "Linux/i386 swap"
  mount.swap:
    - persist: true
```

Comment: Works on Arch Linux as well.

Comment: Note: `swapon -a` probably doesn't do a lot as long as it isn't present in fstab Note2: You might want to check free disk space before creating potentially large files

Comment: Note3: I'm not sure `* 2` works just like that because computations inside yaml don't work AFAIK

Answer (score 4):

Using `fallocate` is instantaneous compared to `dd`. Also, the state below will regenerate the swapfile if you change its size in the pillar. This version also omits the superfluous `swapon -a`, which `mount.swap` handles for you.

```
{% set swapfile = salt['pillar.get']('swapfile', {}) %}
{% set size = swapfile.get('size', grains["mem_total"]) %}
{% set path = swapfile.get('path', '/var/swapfile0') %}

{{ path }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        swapon --show=NAME --noheadings | grep -q "^{{ path }}$" && swapoff {{ path }}
        rm -f {{ path }}
        fallocate -l {{ size }}M {{ path }}
        chmod 0600 {{ path }}
        mkswap {{ path }}
    - unless: bash -c '[[ $(($(stat -c %s {{ path }}) / 1024**2)) = {{ size }} ]]'

  mount.swap:
    - persist: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing to Dan's answer:

```
configuring_swap:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        [ -f /var/swap.1 ] && swapoff /var/swap.1
        dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=3072
        chmod 0600 /var/swap.1
        mkswap /var/swap.1
        swapon /var/swap.1
    - unless:
      - "[ `free -b | awk '/Swap/{print $2}'` -ge 3221225472 ]"
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/fstab
    - text: /var/swap.1  swap  swap  defaults  0 0
    - onlyif:
      - file /var/swap.1 2>&1 | grep -q "Linux/i386 swap"
```

This looks at how much total swap the system has, if it's less than 3GB create a 3GB swap file and make sure it is persistent between reboots via `/etc/fstab`.  If you want to make sure your swappiness config is put in place you can do something like:

```
configure_swappiness:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/sysctl.conf
    - text: vm.swappiness = 10
```

Comment: Why do you append the entry to `/etc/fstab` manually instead of using `mount.swap`?

Comment: @Ced Old habits.